# Graph not being plot

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I have built a JavaScript P5.js program to plot graphs. Everything works apart from the points do not appear on the display, and when they do they don't follow the trend the graph should.

```
function setup() {
  H = 800;
  W = 800;
  wFreq = 20;
  hFreq = 20;
  wDist = H / hFreq;
  hDist = W / wFreq;
  uLength = 10;
  
  createCanvas(W, H);
}

function formula(x) {
  return x*x
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  translate(0, 0)
  
  rect(0, H/2, W, 0);
  rect(W/2, 0, 0, H);
  
  translate(0, H/2);
  for(i = W/2; i -= 1; i > 0) {
    rect((i-0.5) * wDist /2, -uLength/2, 0, uLength);
  }
  
  translate(W/2, -H);
  for(i = H/2; i -= 1; i > 0) {
    rect(-uLength/2,i * (hDist -1) /(4*(10/hFreq)), uLength, 0);
  }
  
  translate(200, 200);
  for(i = -wFreq; i += 1; i < wFreq) {
      rect(i*wDist, formula(i), 1, 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think `0x² + 0x - 0` is what you meant to write

Answer (score 1):

Note that your calls to `translate()` stack.

I'm not sure exactly where you want your points to show up, but to help you debug, I can see the points if I change your `translate(200, 200);` call to `translate(400, 400);` instead.

You'll have to play with the values you pass in to achieve the effect you want. You also might want to look up the `push()` and `pop()` functions in [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/).

You might also consider not using `translate()` at all, and using the coordinates directly in your drawing code.